# Laravel fopen from job and from route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, fopen, jobs

When I run this code from `/test` route, it works well. But when I run it from job or command it fails(fopen cannot find the file). What is the difference of these two ways to run the method?

```
$path = 'tempdir1/tempdir2' /* works from the `/test` route, fails from the job class */
fopen($path, 'r');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is path. That's why you should always use absolute paths for example:

```
public_path('test/tempdir/tempdir2');
```

because you never know from which directory your code will be run.

In Laravel there are many such helpers for example `base_path()` or `storage_path()`